# Generated Subgroup connected in topological group?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a non-abelian, uncountable topological Hausdorff group (not necessarily connected) and $x \in G$. Then of course $\overline{\langle x \rangle}$ is a closed subgroup of $G$. My question is: Under which circumstances (if there are any?) can we say that $\overline{\langle x \rangle}$ is connected in $G$? Thanks for any help in advance - sorry if I may have missed to add additional information!

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. But please consider the following situation: take $G$ be any group and look at $G\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ then for any $x\in G$ the element $(x,1)$ satisfies similar conditions as that of $x$ however it cannot generate a connected subgroup.

Comment: Is there a more concrete case from which this question arose? Perhaps it will be easier to address?

Comment: @Yanko thanks for your quick reply and the example! I guess you endow $G \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology here, right? Keen-amateur: No, this doesn't come from a concrete case to be honest...sorry :/

Comment: @ComplexFlo you only need to endow $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with discrete topology. You can take any topology on $G$.

Comment: In case anybod is interested in the same or a similar question: In any topological space $X$, the closure $\overline{A}$ of a connected subset $A \subseteq X$ is connected. However, in a topoological group $G$, the generated (sub)group $\langle A \rangle$ of a connected subset $A \subseteq G$ is connected only if $A$ contains the identity element $e_G \in G$. Otherwise, a counterexample is given above by @Yanko, and see also the MO post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106150/commutator-of-algebraic-subgroups-is-connected.